# CASBIN url subset block

Tags: casbin

I have following policies:

```
p, alice, /alice_data/:id/using, GET
p, bob, /alice_data/*, GET
```

My current enforcer enforcement result:

```
alice, /alice_data/hello, GET  ->  True
bob, /alice_data/123/using, GET -> True
```

I need to **block bob** for */alice_data/:id/using*

```
alice, /alice_data/hello, GET  ->  i want it to be True
bob, /alice_data/123/using, GET -> i want it to be **False**
```

since */alice_data/123/using* is a subset of */alice_data/** , but i want to block bob for */alice_data/123/using*, **can I do that ?? please guide**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control whether `/alice_data/123/using` matches `/alice_data/*`, you need to use `regexMatch` or define your own `keyMatch`: https://casbin.org/docs/en/function